# Link two near endpoints of a skeleton by a line

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to link the two close endpoints of an image by drawing a line between the points which have shortest distance between them.

[image: green lines, with endpoints marked in yellow, and some nearby yellow dots linked by manually drawn line]

I tried methods that connect scatter points but that does not apply to my code. I have used Shi-Tomasi corner detection to plot the corner points.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv
from scipy.spatial import distance

img = cv2.imread('edge.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
rows, cols = img.shape
canny = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 240)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
dilation = cv2.dilate(canny,kernel,iterations = 1)

size = np.size(img)
skel = np.zeros(img.shape,np.uint8)
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,dilation)
corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(skel,30,0.01,11)
corners = np.int0(corners)
for i in corners:
   x,y = i.ravel()
   cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)

print(corners)

plt.imshow(img),plt.show()

cv2.imshow('Original', dilation)
cv2.imshow('canny', canny)
```

I have endpoints of the image. I just want to link the closest endpoints with a line. I tried it manually as shown in the image above.

Comment: Finding the end points of the skeleton (Canny edges) is trivial, using Shi-Tomasi for that is overkill, and computationally wasteful.

Comment: what do you suggest using then?

Comment: Given that Canny always returns a 1-pixel thick line, you can simply count the number of set neighbors for each point. If there is only one neighbor set, it's an end point. A quick way to count is to convolve the image (assuming set pixels have a value of 1 and background pixels a value of 0) with a 3x3 kernel of ones (`np.ones((3.3))`). The result is 2 for set pixels that have exactly one neighbor (it can also be 2 for non-set pixels, so you need to do a logical AND there). In any case, a 3x3 convolution, a comparison and a logical and is much, much cheaper than Shi-Tomasi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind Guys i got it!

I converted the points array to list and found smallest distance by using euclidean distance function and drew a line